# JobDispatcher.cancel() is not calling onStopJob()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-job-dispatcher

I have used `FirebaseJobDispatcher` in my project. This is the sample code.

```
public class MyCustomDispatcher extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
        Log.e("MyCustomDispatcher", "onStartJob() called with: " + "job = [" + job.getTag() + "]");

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        Log.e("MyCustomDispatcher", "onStopJob() called with: " + "job = [" + job + "]");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And to start my job i have done simple thing in my activity.

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher firebaseJobDispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
Job myJob = firebaseJobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(MyCustomDispatcher.class)
            .setTag("service")
            .setRecurring(false)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0,10))
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
            .build();

firebaseJobDispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

It is starting my service and `onStartJob()` is being called whenever i schedule my job.

Only problem is when i use `firebaseJobDispatcher.cancel("service");`, it is not calling `onStopJob()`.

Is it the actual behavior or is there anything that i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe onStopJob() is only called when your job is stopped before it has completed whatever onStartJob() is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue but when I set `return true` for both methods, `onStopJob` is getting called. I hope it will help you.